# Add two JToken to dictionary as Key/Value pair simultaneously

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json file that contains these information:

```
{
 "type" : "Something", 
 "values" : 
 [ 
     { "type": "Something else", 
       "categories": { 
           "values": [ "Grocery" ]},
        "Name": "Eggs"
    }, 
    { "type": "Something else",
      "categories": { 
          "values": [ "Utensil" ]},
          "Name": "Spoon"
    }
 ]}
```

I'm parsing it like this

```
string jstring = File.ReadAlltext(jsonFile); 
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jstring);
```

Now I want to get only the Name and CategoryValue and make them a Key/value pair in a dictionary. So I start like this:

```
foreach (var item in json["values"]){
  Console.WriteLine(item["categories"]["values"] + ":" + item["Name"]};
```

I get an output of:

> Grocery:Eggs
>
> Utensil:spoon

MY QUESTION: What is the most efficient way to directly Add these information to a dictionary as I retrieve them in that foreach loop?

I have failed trying to use a few JToken properties I found on Newtonsoft's documentation website: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm

I have thought about using String Split and appending to a list but that's hardly efficient and its too clumsy. Please help. I'd greatly appreciate anything I can get. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that each item may have multiple categories, and that the same categories can appear on multiple items?  In that case, you'd want the dictionary to be a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key is the category and the value is a list of all the items that fall under that category.  You can use LINQ methods to create this dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = obj["values"]
    .Select(jo => jo.SelectToken("categories.values")
                    .Select(t => new
                    {
                        Category = (string)t,
                        Name = (string)jo["Name"]
                    }))
    .SelectMany(a => a)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Category)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a => a.Name).ToList());
```

Then:

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", kvp.Value));
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MxRqg6

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly for what I needed!